# How to know when I last logged in from lock mode?

Tags: windows-7

I usually lock my PC with password while going out, but still there is chance one can still access my information by logging in.

So, how do I find out at what time I last logged in?

Answer (score 2):

### How do I find if Windows has been logged in from the lock screen?

Logging in via the lock screen generates a security log trail by default. To find this:

- run `Event Viewer` (<kbd>Win+r</kbd>`-> eventvwr.msc`, or <kbd>Win+x</kbd>`->`<kbd>v</kbd>, or from the Control Panel etc)
- Expand `Windows Logs` in the left-hand pane
- Select the `Security` log type
- Look for `Logon` events, with type `7` (`Logon Type 7 = Unlock Workstation`<sup>1</sup>), for logins from the lock screen

See illustration:

[image: event viewer]

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> per [this source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for Windows logon event types</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you (or your domain administrator) have enabled account auditing, then you can find that information in your Security Event Log.

1. Click <kbd>Start</kbd>
2. Type `Event Viewer` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Select `Windows Logs > Security` from the Event Viewer tree.
4. Look for Audit Success or failure messages marked `Logon`.

Several entries will often appear for any given logon. You can match logon and logoff entries based on the `Logon ID` value within each event detail.

To enable Account Auditing Settings:

1. Click <kbd>Start</kbd>
2. Type `secpol.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Navigate to `Local Policy > Audit Policy`
4. Right click the `Audit account logon events` policy option
5. Select `Properties`.
6. Check both the `Success` and `Failure` check boxes.